# DiskCache encryption and decryption of Glide Images?

Tags: android, caching, encryption, android-glide

How to encrypt and decrypt disk cache images in android using Glide ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi one idea would be create a cache decoder / encoder and use a library such https://github.com/facebook/conceal to do the hard encrypt / decrypt lift.

This image might help you navigate through the life cycle of glide:
[image]